# How Can I Provide Consistency Between Different Databases?

Tags: mongodb, microservices

I want to build an application. The application will have three microservice like content-service1, content-service2, content-service3. Also, each microservice will have its own database. And the application will have a load balancer, Load balancer's mission is distribution (the first request will go to the first container, the second request will go to the second container...). The question is coming... How can ı provide consistency between different databases? I looked at some topics like partitioning, eventual consistency, saga... But I don't understand. Are these the right solution?
[system design that ı want image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJM5U.png)

Comment: why do you need 3x databases when you can have only one database?

Comment: @R2D2 Actually, I don't know whether this approach is good or bad. I just want each microservice to have its own database. (microservice1-mongo1, ms2-mongo2, ms3-mongo3). For example, if microservice1 changes mongo1, ms2 will change mongo2

Comment: Then everything is fine :)

Comment: @R2D2 Thank you, I don't understand. How can I provide consistency? How can ı change mongo2 when mongo1 changed :) Because the three databases must include the same data finally

Comment: okey , but in case you need to have same data in all places better write from all microservices to singe database if you need consistency ... , otherways it become very complex if you will need to replicate in 3x different databases , dont you think?

Comment: @R2D2 maybe you're right. But I want to use database per service pattern but ı think you're right, this looks very complex.

Comment: You can define replicaSet ( 3x pods mongoDB PRIMARY+2x SECONDARY) , your database service will write to the PRIMARY from all 3x microservices and if something go wrong some of your SEC will switch to PRI  - you dont need 3x independent databases  it seems ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing up microservices and application instances.

If `content-service1`, `content-service2` and `content-service3` is backed by the same application (same code) you only have one application (one service).
If you want to have high availability you surely need multiple instances of the same application (simply the same application run 3 times on different servers).

In this case, you don't need to have a database per application instances because all of them will be connected to the same database and you won't have inconsistency issues.

If you don't want to have a single point of failure you should also need to ensure you can have redundancy for your database. Depending on the provider you use, you might have master/slaves or multi-master topology, data replication between database nodes will probably be handled by the database itself.

Microservice is a solution to split big applications in smaller ones. Each microservice will store it's own data in a dedicated database. Microservices are application like others, they can themselves have multiple instances for high availability.